# Is it okay to selling Quran Services in Islam?

Tags: quran, sharia, practical-islam

I have developed my own site for online Quran reading and I have many tutors for this purpose. My plan is to optimize my site in google and get many kids and adults from the world and will provide services to read and learn the Quran online to those kids and adults. Of course, I will pay my tutors too but someone said to me that it is not fair with Islam to sell out Islamic services etc.
I am very confused and feeling guilty about this all that if I did wrong after making a site for this purpose? you can see my site here [online Quran reading](http://www.onlinequranreading.org).

Comment: Related post: [Selling Qur'an and visual impaired](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50469/selling-quran-and-visual-impaired?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imam Nawawi suggests two answers given by those who allow it to hadith ash bin Ubadah Shomit, namely:

That the chains hadith it needs no comment.
It is tabarru '(alms) from people who taught the Qur'an then he does not have the slightest right then that person gave a gift in return for it then it is not permissible for him to pick it up, unlike the people who hire him berakad before teaching. (at Tibyan FII Adab Hamlatil Qur'an thing 57)
If it is a teacher or a teaching institution must determine the amount of the Qur'an as a certain price then let the pay attention to two of the following:

While maintaining sincerity inside of him and do not make such payments as a goal because it will make teaching a hopeless sight of Allah swt.
Sheikh Muhammad Mukhtar as Syinqithi in answering questions about the law taking wages for teaching the sciences Syar'iyah said, "... ath Thobari Imam Ibn Jarir, Al Hafiz Ibn Hajar and other kind found people with knowledge aimed hereafter then get paid from knowledge caused unsettled in getting sustenance then this does not ruin his sincerity during the goal is to teach science and provide benefits to the Muslims. So it is not damaged by the presence of one's sincerity parts of the world, as indicated by the words of the Qur'an and the authentic Sunnah. "(Www.islamweb.net)

Do not let the purpose of teaching the Qur'an is to eradicate illiteracy in the midst of the Qur'an people being reached due to the inability of the people do not pay the price offered.

Read from [source](http://www.eramuslim.com/ustadz-menjawab/menerima-upah-dari-mengajar-dan-membaca-alqur-an.htm#.UYM7nKKSJSM)