# Selling Quran and visual impaired

Tags: halal-haram, quran, practical-islam

I can understand this is a weird question, but I want to help visually impaired friends, and reading [this question about selling services](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8084/selling-quran-services-in-islam), I have many doubts.

I am planning to have a Text-to-Speech service on a website that can read the Quran to blind people, but I don't know if this is considered impolite, "Haram", or worse.

Please excuse if I used incorrect terms, I hope I made myself as clear as possible!

Comment: AFAIK selling Qur'an or more exactly moshaf copies is permissible (majority view), but rather disliked (shafi'i view) if not haraam (hanbali view). While it is strongly encouraged to give it as a gift. The Point here might be how to evaluate the service and i guess it would be allowed to earn from it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Rather than "selling" here I see hoping to just to cover the expenses... while technically it's a sale, I expect to be at loss, actually. Should I see an Imam, just to know about these matters better?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,

It is not "Haram" or wrong,
quite the opposite, it's a great idea

Because your intention is to help,

Evidence of this is what the Prophet Muhammad said in Hadith:

who does something good, has reward and a reward about those who do it, until the Day of Resurrection (Narrated by "Muslim" in his "Saheeh")

in Arabic : من سنَّ سنةً حسنةً فله أجرها وأجرُ من عملَ بها إلى يومِ القيامة

Answer (score -1):

This question has already an answer for it, please view the links below:

- [**Ruling on buying and selling Mushafs**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/171039/ruling-on-buying-and-selling-mushafs)
- [**What is the ruling of selling the Mushaf (Qur’aan)?**](http://www.fatwaislam.com/fis/index.cfm?scn=fd&ID=666)

Comment: The Mushaf of the Quran can be sold and is sold since it takes labor and material to compile it, and it is unlikely that a bookstore would give you one for free, though Dawah groups and individual Muslims might be willing to do so.  The Quran, as in the word of Allah, is not made but an uncreated attribute of Allah, at least according to the Ahlul Sunnah.  **"** *If it is on sale Quran, you do not need it. You need only free. The true Quran is free and not on sale.* **"** <--- this statement makes no sense.

Comment: @UmH how come Quran is uncreated? Quran is one of the things which God has created including the divine laws.

Comment: According to the Ahlus Sunnah, Quran is the speech of Allah, so it is His *sift* and not a creation, since calling it a creation would be ascribing creation of an attribute of Allah.

Comment: @UmH can you bring me a price? So that I may believe in this? And what is sift?

Comment: No, I can not bring you a "price".

Comment: @UmH I meant prove, not price‍♂️ that’s due to the stupid correction of my keyboard.

Comment: @UmH first of, word of God means, that the words in this book are truth. In reality He doesn’t need us, before the creation, there was no Quran, no divine laws, only God by Himself, and after He decided To Create something, He also created Quran, and He Protected Quran, and that’s the meaning of word of God. And if He wishes, He can change any law He Made, because He is the only true Law Maker. He decided to prohibit us to steal and do such things. He decided that us to pray to Him in the way He wants, because He does what He wants. He doesn’t need not even Quran. Because, He is Supreme.

Comment: @UmH He created Islam and Quran, because He has Absolute Free Will. If He wants, He can even destroy Quran. Because, He is the Creator of Quran.

Comment: I have no intention of debating this with you, I was simply pointing out that what you are passing as an answer is a heretical belief. If you want proof then you can probably look online, e.g. [here](https://islamqa.info/en/10153), [here](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=E&Id=29238), [here](https://islamqa.info/en/227441) etc. And Allah has made a distinction between His creation and command in e.g. [7:54](https://quran.com/7/54).

Comment: @UmH Oh, don’t take it in this way. I only try to make things logic only. Because, all what I know is that God is the Only Being who is uncreated.

Comment: To me this answer seem to have missed the Topic. The matter here is not related to Qur'an nor moshaf it is about a Service related to Qur'an for blind People.